# simple scalar question- is there a scalar such that...

Tags: calculus

can someone please show me how to do j? thanks very much -- actually now that I look at it is it simply:  m(v+2w) = (o,o,1)?
[image]

Comment: Yes; you'd need to determine if it has a solution. But if you just compute ${\bf v}+2\bf w$, is it a scalar multiple of $(0,0,1)$?

Answer (score 0):

You look for a solution to $m(v+2w)=(0,0,1)$. For such an $m$ to exist, you need that $k$ and $v+2w$ are linearly dependent, this is not the case since $v+2w=(5,7,0)$. If there was such a scalar, you would need $5m=0$, $7m=0$ and $0m=1$. These equations can't be solved.

Comment: thanks makes perfect sense although any clarification on what linearly dependent means would be great

Comment: Two vectors $x$ and $y$ are said to be linearly independent if the equation $ax + by=0$, with a,b scalars, implies that $a=b=0$. If this doesn't happen, they're linearly dependent.